# Connecting a html page with a servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I want to store the user's input in a database using a servlet.
I tried adding a form tag having an attribute action to map it with the webservlet annotation but it didn't work. I need help on how to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#create_btn').click(function () {
            $('#textArea').show();
            $('#post_btn').show();
            $('#cancel_btn').show();
});
        $('#cancel_btn').click(function () {
            $('#textArea').hide('slow');
            $('#post_btn').hide('slow');
            $('#cancel_btn').hide('slow');
        });
        $('#post_btn').click(function () {
            // body...
            var note = $('#textArea').val();
            $('<li>').text(note).prependTo('.notes');
            $('#textArea').val('');
            $('#post_btn').addClass('disabled');
        });


        $('#textArea').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        if (postLength <= 0) {
            $('#post_btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#post_btn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
    });
         $('#post_btn').addClass('disabled');

    });



</script>
</head>






<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"></ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="SearchServlet">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search_text" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="SignOutServlet">Sign Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<form action="CreateServlet">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!--<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#textArea">Create</button>-->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="create_btn">Create</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name = "Note_Area" id="textArea" placeholder="Write down something here..." style="display: none; margin-top: 10px;"></textarea>
        <grammarly-btn><div style="z-index: 2; opacity: 1; transform: translate(408.156px, 43px);" class="_9b5ef6-textarea_btn _9b5ef6-anonymous _9b5ef6-not_focused" data-grammarly-reactid=".0">
        <div class="_9b5ef6-transform_wrap" data-grammarly-reactid=".0.0">
        <div title="Protected by Grammarly" class="_9b5ef6-status" data-grammarly-reactid=".0.0.0">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <span class="_9b5ef6-btn_text" data-grammarly-reactid=".0.1"></span></div></grammarly-btn>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id = post_btn style="display: none; ">Post</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="cancel_btn" style="display: none;">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="notes"></ul>
</div>
 </div>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

java code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(description = "For creating notes", urlPatterns = { "/CreateServlet" })
public class CreateServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private int i=0;
    private String note;
    private String email;
    private String password;



    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://LENOVO:1433;database=Minor;integratedSecurity=true;"); 

            note = request.getParameter("Note_Area");
            System.out.println(note);

            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if(session != null)
            {   
                String id = request.getRequestedSessionId();
                System.out.println(id);

                email =(String)session.getAttribute("emailadd");
                password=(String)session.getAttribute("password");

                System.out.println(email);
                System.out.println(password);

                ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Notes(MailAdd,Note) values(?,?)");
                ps.setString(1, email);
                ps.setString(2, note);
                i = ps.executeUpdate();

                if(i==0)
                {
                    System.out.println("No note has been saved");
                    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Note has been saved");
                    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                response.sendRedirect("signin.html");
                System.out.println("Session Expired!!!");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                con.close();
                ps.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What error were you getting when you had a form with an action?

Comment: where is the servlet ?

Comment: Your html is so messed up, where is <body> tag